# Extracting values from function/list containing arguments/elements (using patterns)

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, pattern-matching

Here's an example input list:

```
list = {SomeFunction[v1, arg -> "val"], 
  SomeFunction[v2, target -> "targetVal"], 
  SomeFunction[v3, arg -> "val", target -> "targetVal"]}
```

I want to extract the first argument of each function in the list which contains the argument `target -> "targetVal"`. Example output:

```
list = {SomeFunction[v1, arg -> "val"], 
  "extractedVal" -> v2, 
  "extractedVal" -> v3}
```

Here's a naive way to achieve this:

```
list /. {SomeFunction[x_, target -> "targetVal"] -> ("extractedVal" -> x),
  SomeFunction[x_, arg -> "val", target -> "targetVal"] -> ("extractedVal" -> x)}
```

The problem with this approach is that one has to list all the variants of the function with different combinations of arguments, in order for `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) to work. How do I achieve the intended output by simply supplying the condition that the function must contain the required argument (multple arguments may be required)?

I'm trying to utilize Mathematica's ability to parse RTF files to extract elements containing certain styles, which are given as "arguments" in `StyleBox` function/objects. I will be extracting multiple items at once.

Comment: See [`BlankNullSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html) (`___`): `list /. SomeFunction[x_, ___, target -> "targetVal", ___] :> x`

Comment: That is good if there's one required argument, but what if there's multiple? The order of the argument seems to matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two approaches:

- Using [`BlankNullSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html) (`___`) and [`OrderlessPatternSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html):

  ```
  {
    f[x1, a -> 1, b -> 2],
    f[x2, b -> 2, a -> 1],
    f[x3, c -> 2, a -> 1, d -> 5, b -> 2, e -> 6],
    f[x4, e -> 5, b -> 2, c -> 2, a -> 1, d -> 3]
    } /. f[x_, OrderlessPatternSequence[___, a -> 1, ___, b -> 2, ___]] :> x
  (* {x1, x2, x3, x4} *)
  ```
- Using [`Condition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) (`/;`):

  ```
  {
    f[x1, a -> 1, b -> 2],
    f[x2, b -> 2, a -> 1],
    f[x3, c -> 2, a -> 1, d -> 5, b -> 2, e -> 6],
    f[x4, e -> 5, b -> 2, c -> 2, a -> 1, d -> 3]
   } /. f[x_, opts__Rule] /; ({a, b} /. {opts}) == {1, 2} :> x
  (* {x1, x2, x3, x4} *)
  ```

Answer (score 3):

```
list /. _[v_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] /; 
  FilterRules[{opts}, {target}] != {} :> "extractedValue" -> v
```

> {SomeFunction[v1, arg -> "val"],
>    "extractedValue" -> v2,
>    "extractedValue" -> v3}

Alternatively, use the same replacement rule with `Replace` at level 1:

```
Replace[list, _[v_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] /; 
   FilterRules[{opts}, {target}] != {} :> "extractedValue" -> v, 1]
```

> {SomeFunction[v1, arg -> "val"],
>    "extractedValue" -> v2,
>    "extractedValue" -> v3}